# Please help find these paintings

Tags: art, italy, renaissance, paris

I've read in a book written about 80 years ago descriptions of 3 paintings,
the paintings were seen about 130 years ago.

These are the descriptions (translated to English):

**Painting #1**

Painting of a battle field, on a high place the commanders stand and look through some sort of telescope how their soldiers fight, on one side there are rivers of blood and two people are fighting, from another side injured people with chopped legs and broken hands. Nurses carrying 3 injured people on one bed with a doctor walking near them, but a bullet explodes and hits the doctor and one of the nurses so the injured people are falling into a deep pit. A fighter riding on a horse is being thrown away in the air with his horse by a bullet hitting them. Another fighter is riding on a horse and swing his sword with his right hand, with his left hand he's holding his horses bridle.

**Painting #2**

A field with grain, one part of it has wheat the other has barley. On the side of the field there's a road. The sky is bright and the sun is shining. On top of one wheat in the field stands a small bird. On the end of the field there's a tree with many branches and on one of the branches sitting a raven.

**Painting #3**

A court in Rome, prisoners are tied, judges, a prosecutor and a pleader. A small child standing on a chair pointing on the crowd with one finger and looking on the judges. The person being judged is sitting with his head between his knees.

**Some background:** The book's author is known to be accurate about details. He mentions that the paintings were made by "The known and famous artist [Raphael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raphael)". He also states that the first 2 paintings were reviewed by thousands of known artists. (I'm not sure but they were probably seen at the Louvre Museum). However I couldn't find the paintings while searching the web for Raphael's paintings. I've tried to go through [this web site](http://www.wga.hu/frames-e.html?/html/r/raphael/index.html) and also [this web site](http://www.raphaelsanzio.org/) to no avail. I also went through the Catalogue of Raphaels work in the book ["Raphael: His Life, Works and Times by Eugène Müntz"](http://www.ebooksread.com/dl2.php?action=output_file&id=265315&ext=pdf_external&f=raphaelhislifewo00mn&a_id=34552) which @user2448131 suggests in his comment, but I didn't manage to track them there also.

**Please help me find these paintings.**

Comment: What exactly are you hoping for people here to do? Find where the paintings are? Find photos of the paintings? Find better descriptions of the paintings?

Comment: @KillingTime - Photos of the paintings would be great. The descriptions I wrote are detailed, if someone manage to find the paintings I'm sure he would recognize them by the descriptions.

Comment: Do you happen to have any more information on the book that referenced the images?

Comment: #2 is strange, for Raphael wasn't fond of painting landscapes for the sake of landscapes. Perhaps it is a detail of the background of one of his portraits? #1 allso seems out of character for Raphael; he did paint a few battle scenes, or directed their painting by his assistants, but none that I could locate (*The Battle of the Milvian Bridge*, probably executed by Giulio Romano, and *The Battle of Ostia*) matches your description - and are frescoes, not canvasses. #3 looks - or sounds - more like something Raphael would paint, but I was also unable to find it among his works in the internet.

Comment: Is it possible the book just got the authorship wrong on those works?

Comment: @T.E.D. - It's an Hebrew book and its author is known to be very very accurate about details. He says explicitly that those three paintings were made by "The known and famous artist Raphael" and he says about the first 2 paintings that they were reviewed by thousands of known artists.

Comment: Look at [Raphael: His Life, Works and Times](https://books.google.com/books?id=P-81AAAAMAAJ) by Eugène Müntz -January 1, 1888.  This is published about the time you indicate the paintings were in the Louvre.  It contains a Catalogue of Raphaels works, including locations.

Comment: Could you tell us about the book you read this in? The author and name would be very helpful. Raphael doesn't seem like a likely painter of all three. Especially #1 seems to be set later than his own time period. The description says 18/19th century to me, such gruesome battle depictions and widespread use of firearms don't seem like 1500 to me. Also telescopes/spyglasses were invented around 1600 and I've never heard of a similar device used on the battlefield before that.

Comment: If there are nurses in the field in #1, the scene likely wasn't painted before the Crimean War.

Comment: @Dulkan: Female nurses, particularly in any sort of uniform, would be post Crimean War when Florence Nightingale founded the profession. (Sabre or lance-equipped) cavalry in the same picture pretty much limits #1 to the two generations between the 1850's and the mid 1920's.

Comment: @Dulkan (and a lot of other commenters): it's from a letter in Hebrew by Rabbi Yosef Yitzchak Schneersohn (6th Lubavitcher Rebbe, 1880-1950), written in 1935, and published in his collected letters ([vol. 3, pp. 389ff](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=31619#p=429)). He's quoting his father, Rabbi Shalom Dovber Schneersohn (1860-1920), speaking in 1891 of having seen these paintings during his travels at some (unspecified) earlier time.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: in the Hebrew original, the nurses are described using the Hebrew masculine אחים, so they would be male nurses (or whatever such personnel would have been called in Raphael's time).

Comment: It occurs to me: maybe the original description was that these paintings weren't by Raphael, but by members of the Pre-Raphaelite Brotherhood? That might fit the (assumed) style and content of the paintings better.

Comment: @Meir - No, it's written explicitly in that [letter](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=31619#p=434&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=) that the paintings were drawn "by the known and famous artist Raphael".

Answer (score 4):

Scholarship on Raphael's works is continually advancing. Many "lost" works by Rafael have been rediscovered in recent years. Some of his previous works have been reattributed to others. It is important to include these changes in one's research by using modern reference materials. One potential source would be a catalogue raisonnee of the artist's work, such as *Raphael: a Critical Catalogue of His Paintings, Volume 2: the Roman Religious Paintings, Ca. 1508-1520 [Catalogue Raisonne, Catalog Raisonné, Complete Works, Life and Work, Raisonnee]*.

After doing one's own research, it would might make sense to consult with an art historian who specializes in the relevant period, category, or artist. You can find these experts by searching the directory of the [Association of Art Historians](http://www.datawareonline.co.uk/aah/Default.aspx?tabid=83).